# GitLab: Is there a way to protect a branch from command line?

Tags: git, gitlab

Am aware of how its done from the GitLab UI (http://gitlabdomain.com/ProjectNamespace/Project/protected_branches), but is there a way to "Protect" a particular branch from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you need a third-party command-line tool for that though, or use the REST API directly yourself.

Check http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gitlab/frames which is listed on https://about.gitlab.com/applications/

Comment: Thanks, it was combination of answer provided by @marcolz and codeWizard. I did it using combination of REST API & curl. Following is how it could be done. curl -X PUT http://gitlabdomain.com/api/v3/projects/:id/repository/branches/:branch_name/protect?private_token=<private_token>

Comment: As of now, I find none of the 3rd party CLI tools for git(lab|hub) satisfactory in general, and if you want to do more then one thing, you will end up having to use the REST API anyway, most likely. It is also easy to use, and much more powerful, so I would recommend doing all things with that, and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

You cant protect branch from the command line.

Git doesn't know how did you execute the command.
All the gui tools are executing git commands which are CLI behind the scenes.

So your answer is **NO**

What you can do might be able to pass special parameter along with the git lag commands `-c` flag to any command and then check it in your server hooks to verify that the command came from GUI and not from CLI.