# GitLab - Determine if branch is protected from terminal git command

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there a method to determine if a branch is protected in GitLab using the `git` command?

Preferably an approach to determine protected status without trying to do something illegal and receiving a warning.

Comment: Protected-ness is not really a Git thing, it's an add-on. There might be some web endpoint that makes it easy to query using `curl` or something along those lines, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using curl.

Answer (score 3):

Protected branch isn't a git feature.

It's a feature of tools like gitlab or github.

Maybe you can get the protected branch of a repository through gitlab api and make verification before you push.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html

Comment: That's why I specified that the branch is protected in GitLab. I'm looking at the api right now. Trying to do something illegal to a protected branch such as `git push --delete origin <protected_branch>` warns that they can only be deleted from the web interface. I wanted an approach using only Git that can make this distinction without trying to do something illegal like deleting it using the above command.

Comment: Saying it’s not a Git feature isn’t quite correct. Git protocol *requires* a [reference discovery](https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol/2.16.6#_smart_clients) step, during which the client specifies service wanted (e.g., `git-receive-pack` service if you want to push) and the server responds with a list of refs. It would seem like if some branches cannot be pushed to by current user, they should not be listed in ref discovery response *for push*. If Github/Gitlab list protected branches when you ask for push, it should probably be considered as their non-compliance with Git protocol.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way you can do that using `git` command-line.**

But, there an alternative. You can install - a pypi module:

```
pip install python-gitlab
```

[Here](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is the documentation, you can refer.

To get the information about the protected branches, you can do:

```
p_branches = project.protectedbranches.list()
```

using python.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509475/gitlab-is-there-a-way-to-protect-a-branch-from-command-line) is another question I found, which is similar to yours.

> Edit:
>
> [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) is the gitlab api. The
>   endpoint to get the protected branches is give as:
>
> ```
> /projects/:id/protected_branches
> ```

Comment: If there's a way to do it with a Python library that probably means there's an API endpoint. Since the OP didn't say anything about Python a more agnostic answer about the API is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks cris. Gitlab api is available here - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/ with the endpoint - /projects/:id/protected_branches